# Using System.Xml.XmlReader, parse the DTD if present but don't fail if absent

Tags: c#, xml, dtd

I want to parse XML documents that may or may not have a DTD. If there is a DTD, then I want to use it to expand entity references. If there is no DTD (more strictly, if there is no DOCTYPE declaration), I just want to ignore DTD processing.

When I set `XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing=Ignore`, parsing of documents containing entity references fails because the entity is treated as undeclared.

When I set `XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing=Parse`, parsing of documents having no DOCTYPE declaration fails with a rather obscure diagnostic:

```
The empty string '' is not a valid name. (Parameter 'docTypeName')
System.ArgumentException: The empty string '' is not a valid name. (Parameter 'docTypeName')
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.InitializeFreeFloatingDtd(String baseUri, String docTypeName, String publicId, String systemId, String internalSubset, IDtdParserAdapter adapter)
   at System.Xml.DtdParser.System.Xml.IDtdParser.ParseFreeFloatingDtd(String baseUri, String docTypeName, String publicId, String systemId, String internalSubset, IDtdParserAdapter adapter)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDtdFromParserContext()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ProcessDtdFromParserContext(XmlParserContext context)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitStream()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(Stream stream, Byte[] bytes, Int32 byteCount, XmlReaderSettings settings, Uri baseUri, String baseUriStr, XmlParserContext context, Boolean closeInput)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(Stream input, Uri baseUri, String baseUriString, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(Stream input, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
```

Is there any setting that will handle both cases, or do I need to peek at the content first and set the parser up accordingly?

I suspect this may have something to do with the `XmlParserContext` (given that this features on the stack trace), but I don't know how to initialise the `XmlParserContext` given that I don't know what's in the document in advance. I supplied an `XmlParserContext` in which no value was supplied for `docTypeName`.

Comment: If performance is not an issue you could try `Ignore` if `Parse` fails.

Comment: did you try without the XmlParserContext parameter?

Comment: I've gone deeper into the case where I set DtdProcessing=Parse, and it's still not resolving the entity reference, so there's something else I'm missing.

Comment: @Dialecticus that would be a horrible last resort. Peeking at the input stream is probably a lesser evil, but still horrible.

Comment: You could also try `Prohibit` first. It will fail early in parsing process, with more useful text, and if it fails then use `Parse`. `Prohibit` does the peeking for you.

Comment: You could also copy all the relevant source code starting with [XmlReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReader.cs), only to add new value `TryParse` to enum [DtdProcessing](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/DtdProcessing.cs), and additional functionality in the critical [switch](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,2792). There is no middle solution, since all classes are closed, with internal and private methods, and nothing is virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I've solved it. I went down a number of false trails, some of my own making, some triggered by poor documentation.

I'm now creating a parser like this, whether or not there is a DOCTYPE declaration:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 1024;
settings.XmlResolver = new MyXmlResolver(new Uri(source.getSystemId()));
xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(inputStream, settings);
```

There's no need for an `XmlParserContext` object, it only seems to get in the way (and I still don't know what it really does).

I didn't find a way to supply the parser with both an input stream and a base URI, so I instead use my own XmlResolver which knows the base URI, and uses that in place of the one supplied to the XmlResolver's `ResolveUri` method.

The failures I was observing were caused as follows:

(a) The `System.ArgumentException` was caused by my attempt to supply an `XmlParserContext` and went away when I switched to a constructor that didn't use one. (Thanks, @jdweng).

(b) The "entity not declared" error was caused by a silent failure to resolve the DTD system-id, which in turn was caused by the fact that I hadn't found any successful way to supply the parser with a base URI (my attempt to do this using an `XmlParserContext` having proved misguided).